# Image of a Lipschitz domain

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

I have a question about Lipschitz domain.

Let $D$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. Let $\Phi$ be a Lipschitz continuous function defined on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$.

**My question**

Is $\Phi(D)$ a Lipschitz domain?

If you know references about this assertion, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No since $\Phi$ can be for example a constant map.